# Display Image Sourced from Library In Page Layout

Tags: web-part, page-layout

I am creating a custom page layout with default webparts in a webpart zone.  I need to display a single picture sourced from an Image Library on my page preferably dynamically.  This picture will be different on each team site that utilizes the layout, but have the same styles/dimensions applied.

Ideally, I would like the user to be able to edit only that webpart with the URL to the source of the image.  Here is what I tried and the challenge I am facing:

- I have an Image Viewer Webpart placed in my WebPart Zone.
- I changed the Webpart Zone snippet to **AllowLayoutChange: False**.  This satisfied my need to disable the user from adding a bunch of webparts to that Webpart Zone.  However, this option also disables the user from being able to add the URL to the Image Viewer Webpart.

Is there any other way I can achieve something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using RichImageField in the page layout.

Ex:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField ID="pageImage" runat="server" FieldName="PublishingRollupImage" />
```